# Dividing a column into multiple ones

Tags: r

I have a long list that looks something like this:

```
Sample 1 
1        
2        
3  
Sample 2  
4
5
6
Sample 3
7
8
9
```

And I would like to turn it into this:

```
Sample 1 Sample 2  Sample 3
   1        4         7  
   2        5         8 
   3        6         9
```

I'm guessing the solution would be to possibly grep "Sample" and somehow move everything that's under it into a new column, but I cannot figure out how to do that (especially without any packages). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the number of samples in a sample always the same?

Comment: @Afrin  Please stop mass suggesting edits with irrelevant fluff -- have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: @tavdp I should've mentioned this, my bad. They're not the same, no.

Comment: @mark1245 then it seems to me that a matrix or dataframe is not the right choice of data representation. How would you know which variable belongs to which row / where to place the NAs. A list with vectors for each sample feels more natural to me.

Comment: @tavdp That's what I was trying to figure out - if, perhaps, there was a way to generate a df that woud create a new column after recognising the pattern 'Sample'. Thank you for your response, though, I will change my approach to working with this data instead.

Comment: @mark1245 You're welcome :) Since I've given it a thought anyway, you might wanna use something like `which(sample_data_vector %like% "Sample")`, which returns the indices of the vector where the value is like "Sample"

Answer (score 1):

assuming the samples size is the same, transform list to matrix

```r
list <- list('Sample 1', 
         '1',
         '2',
         '3',
         'Sample 2',  
         '4',
         '5',
         '6',
         'Sample 3',
         '7',
         '8',
         '9')

mat <- matrix(list,nrow = 4)
colnames(mat) <- mat[1,] # first row as names
df <- as.data.frame(mat[-1,]) # remove names form first row & convert to data.frame
```

out

```
  Sample 1 Sample 2 Sample 3
1        1        4        7
2        2        5        8
3        3        6        9
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I left out this important detail - the sample sizes are, indeed, different..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the pattern is repeated an equal number of times, an option would be to split the df up into equal parts, into a list, and then bind the list into columns:

```
library(rlist)
n=4
nr=nrow(dat)
list.cbind(split(dat, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr)))
```

```
       1.V1     2.V1     3.V1
1: Sample 1 Sample 2 Sample 3
2:        1        4        7
3:        2        5        8
4:        3        6        9
```

```
dat = fread('Sample 1 
1        
2        
3  
Sample 2  
4
5
6
Sample 3
7
8
9    ', header=F)
```